# Laravel 5 Routing with Auth

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Hello**!

I'm trying to learning **laravel**, and i started with doing a page that only **logged people can access** ( I don't have login yet ) , but i'm just testing, so far i have:

**Routes.php**:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', function () {
    return view('index');
}]);


Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

Ok, this file contains the routes , i searched how to give a name to the route, so i can redirect user to that route when he don't have access.

My other file is **home.blade.php**:

```
<?php 

if (!Auth::check()){    
    return Redirect::route('index');        
} 

?>
```

So is that the best way to check if user is logged? I gave a name to the route, index , so if user is not logged i want to redirect back to index, is not working tho, i want to know if this is the best option to achieve my goal.

**Thank you**.

Comment: are you getting any errors? simply use auth middle ware to check login

Comment: When i try to access the home page, i get a blank page , but i don't get redirect to index.

Comment: So your login page is index page? and home page is page after login success

Comment: Yes , you're right!  But i don't have a login yet, i'm just trying to see if the redirect is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, as said at [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#protecting-routes) is:

```
    Route::get('/home', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
        // here will be only authorized access
        return view('home');
    }]);
```

Auth middleware defined by default.

Comment: Oh i see, it redirect me to the login page, it is my goal, is there any way to redirect to index page instead auth/login , thank you anyway for the answer!

Comment: You can modify middleware as you want. You can find it at app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

Answer (score 0):

use Auth; loading facades

```
if (Auth::check()){    

if(Auth::Guest()):
return Redirect::route('index');       
endif; 

} 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer sir, but, i will restrict the access on the route page, anyway thank you man!